# Loop over number preceded by underscore symbol in R

Tags: r, loops

I apologize in advance but I did not find what I need in previous topic-related posts.

Suppose that I have the following data. "bchain" is a dataframe of 2192 observations. The column "Date" contains dates from 2011/01/01 to 2016/12/31. The column "Value" contains daily exchange rates.

```
>bchain

         Date       Value
1    2011-01-01    0.299998
2    2011-01-02    0.299996
3    2011-01-03    0.299998
4    2011-01-04    0.299899
5    2011-01-05    0.298998
6    2011-01-06    0.299000
7    2011-01-07    0.322000
8    2011-01-08    0.322898
.    .......       .......
```

What I want to do is to visualize the exchange rates year by year in separate plots and save the six graphs on my desktop by using a "for" loop. Consider this simple following pseudo-code which I built around this post content:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/

```
PSEUDO-CODE:

Date_2011=bchain[1:365,1]
Date_2012=bchain[366:731,1]
Date_2013=bchain[732:1096,1]
Date_2014=bchain[1097:1461,1]
Date_2015=bchain[1462:1826,1]
Date_2016=bchain[1827:2192,1]

bchain_2011=bchain[1:365,2]
bchain_2012=bchain[366:731,2]
bchain_2013=bchain[732:1096,2]
bchain_2014=bchain[1097:1461,2]
bchain_2015=bchain[1462:1826,2]
bchain_2016=bchain[1827:2192,2]

years=2011:2016
for(i in years){
mypath = file.path("C:/Users/toshiba1/Desktop",paste("myplot_", years[i], ".jpg", sep = ""))
jpeg(file=mypath)
mytitle = paste("my title is", years[i])
plot(Date_[i],bchain_[i], main = mytitle)
dev.off()
}
```

Then I get the following error message: object "Date_" not found. I suspect that the problem is that the above loop does not recognize the numbers which come after the underscore sign. So, any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach avoiding the need to make the year-specific data frames. I used the `lubridate` package to extract the year from the date values, generated a `data.frame` of that year, and plotted those data. As @Konrad also pointed out, the way in which you call some of the objects is giving you issues - I cleaned up some of those in your `paste` statements below.

```
library(lubridate)

# Create toy data to plot
bchain <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2011-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-12-31"),
                                 by = 1),
                 Value = runif(2192, 0, 1))

years <- 2011:2016
for(i in years){
  # Create dataset of just data to plot
  bchain_plot <- bchain[year(bchain$Date) == i, ]

  # Edited file name w/i jpeg call and fixed paste statement
  jpeg(filename=paste0("C:/Users/toshiba1/Desktop/myplot_", i, ".jpg"))

  # Plot data w/ title included in plot call  
  plot(bchain_plot$Date, bchain_plot$Value, main = paste("my title is", i))

  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: I edited my response to deal with the switch error - I had a typo in the `jpeg(` call but that should work now.

Comment: No, `year()` is the `lubridate` function that returns the year of a date. In your data set, are those values stored as dates or character values? Try running `str(bchain)` to make sure that it's stored as a Date object.

Comment: Yes I later figured out that year is the lubridate package function.

Answer (score 1):

You should call your object properly one approach may involve making use of [`get`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/get) on the lines:

```
# Now plot data number i 
x <- get(paste("Date", i, sep = "_"))
# Plot
plot(x)
```

or simply by nesting:

```
plot(get(paste("Date", i, sep = "_")))
```

To test it, see what happens if you type `Date_[i]` in R console? Are you getting the object you want to pass to the `plot` function? Arrive at the desired object via `get` or any other mechanism that suits you and then pass it to the plotting function.

*I reckon that you want to iterate through your objects - you need `i` **not `[i]`.** Type `[i]` in the R console and see what happens.*

Comment: I used the get command in place of Date_[i] and bchain_[i] and I overcame the problem that I stated before. So thank you a lot. However, I do not know why R returns just the first plot (2011) and not the following ones. Could you explain me why?